# Constructing CON statement in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I have this expression that works in the QGIS Raster Calculator but not ArcGIS Raster Calculator.

How can I reconstruct it?

It is a binary raster that I am working with.

```
("Outputs\Model Fin" == 1 & "Outputs\Obs Fin" == 1) * 1 + ("Outputs\Model Fin" == 1 & "Outputs\Obs Fin" == 0) * 2 + ("Outputs\Model Fin" == 0 & "Outputs\Obs Fin" == 1) * 3 + ("Outputs\Model Fin" == 0 & "Outputs\Obs Fin" == 0) * 4
```

Comment: Spaces in filenames are apt to cause difficulty. At a minimum, make `Raster` objects out of the paths (which should include format file suffixes).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll have a go at it.